# Unity 2019.1/.2 doesn't launch on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-unity, unity3d

I have both installed Unity 2019 with Unity Hub and from the Unity website:
When I launch it nothing happens, the application is running but it does nothing and doesn't open. I can't even provide further logs, that's about it. (Any version prior to that works just fine)

My computer's details:

- Operating System - Fedora 29 Twenty Nine (x86-64)
- Linux Kernel - 5.0.7-200.fc29.x86_64
- Processor - Intel© Core™ i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 2
- Graphics Card - Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XT [Radeon HD 7790/8770 / R7 360 / R9 260/360 OEM] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself when I updated to Fedora 30.
I didn't format my computer but just updated progressively with system updates